# How to intertwine Async functions and sync functions in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am a beginner to flutter and I don't quite understand how to use Async functions in flutter.
For example,

```
Future <String> readData() async {
  final file = await localFile;
  String body = await file.readAsString();
  return body;
}
```

So in this code, I retrieve some data from a local file. But I want to run this function at the start of the app and want to display the result.

Unfortunately, my build function in main.dart is a synchronous one and when I do:

```
child : Text(readData());
```

It does not work due to the fact that it returns a Future . I can't use the await keyword either because it Build is not async.
How do I go about waiting to get this string and display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using **FutureBuilder**

```
  child: FutureBuilder<String>(
      builder: (context, data) {
        return Text(data.hasData ? data.data : '');
      },
      future: readData(),
  ),
```

Comment: You can also using a variable in State of StatefullWidget and setState when file.readAsString() completed.

Answer (score 0):

[Dart Streams - Flutter in Focus](https://youtu.be/nQBpOIHE4eE)

This is very well explained I think should help you

Comment: Thanks for this, can you give me some context in terms of code as to what I can do?